# Failed prop type: The `` is marked as required in ``, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am using flow and passing the state from another component.I am using proptypes and statetypes.How can I solve this error?  Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `business_size` of type `string` supplied to `RoiCalculator`, expected `number`.
    in RoiCalculator

webpack/roi_calculator/main.jsx

```
 export type StateType = {
  business_size: number,
  organisation_name: string,
  pay_period: boolean,
  timesheet_savings: number,
  roster_optimisation: number,
  reduction_time: number,
  elimination_award: number,
  annual_savings: number,
  annual_subscription: number,
  roi: number,
}

export type PropsType = {
  business_size: number,
  organisation_name: string,
  pay_period: boolean,
  timesheet_savings: number,
  roster_optimisation: number,
  reduction_time: number,
  elimination_award: number,
  annual_savings: number,
  annual_subscription: number,
  roi: number,
}

export default class RoiCalculator extends 
 React.Component<PropsType, StateType> {
 constructor (props: PropsType) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     business_size: this.props.business_size,
     organisation_name: this.props.organisation_name,
     pay_period: this.props.pay_period,
     timesheet_savings: 0,
     roster_optimisation: 0,
     reduction_time: 0,
     elimination_award: 0,
     annual_savings: 0,
     annual_subscription: 0,
     roi: 0,
   }
 }

<RoiAssumptions results={this.state}/>
```

webpack/roi_calculator/views/RoiAssumptions/index.jsx

```
export type PropsType = {
  business_size: number,
  organisation_name: string,
  pay_period: boolean,
  timesheet_savings: number,
  roster_optimisation: number,
  reduction_time: number,
  elimination_award: number,
  annual_savings: number,
  annual_subscription: number,
  roi: number,
}
 const t = (key, ...args) => globalT(`js.roi_calculator.${key}`, ...args)

export default class RoiAssumptions extends 
React.Component<PropsType, StateType> {
  constructor (props: PropsType) {
     super(props)
  }

        <div className={styles.aside__value}>
          <p>$ 
{this.roundOffResult(this.props.results.timesheet_savings)}</p>      
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is `this.props.business_size` first getting set?  It looks like somehow it is getting a string value.  If it's coming from a backend API of some sort, you need to convert it to a number before passing it as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

Granted that the error suggested in the title (required field has value `undefined`) and the error in the question (invalid type `string`, expected `number`) are slightly different, I will attempt a solution for the latter. I would look for any places where `RoiCalculator` is rendered an check that the `prop` for `business_size` is not passed as a string. For instance the following snippets would violate the prop type check:

```
<RoiCalculator business_size="30" {...otherProps}/>
<RoiCalculator business_size={"30"} {...otherProps}/>
```

This would however be correct

```
<RoiCalculator business_size={30} {...otherProps}/>
```